# How using sed one can find and replace a pattern with multiple strings?

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I got this `x.xx.xxx.xxxx.api-6.8.25-SNAPSHOT.jar` filename, which I would like to change to, `x.xx.xxx.xxxx.api_6.8.25.SNAPSHOT.jar`. using `sed` I came up with this:

```
 FILENAME=$(sed 's/-(?=[\w])/_/g' <<< "$FILENAME")
```

The regex pattern seems to be correct in pointing `-`s, however when my script runs no change is applied on my string. what I'm missing here? and how can I have multiple substitutions? changing the first dash with an underscore and the second with a dot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sh
FILENAME=$(sed -E 's/(.*)-([0-9.]+)-/\1_\2./' <<< "$FILENAME")
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/eNdXSK).

*Details*:

- `-E` enables POSIX ERE syntax
- `(.*)-([0-9.]+)-` - a regex that matches and captures into Group 1 any zero or more chars, then `-`, then one or more digits or dots captured into Group 2 and then a  `-`
- `\1_\2.` is the replacement, Group 1, `_`, Group 2 and a `.`.

Comment: This works perfectly but can you please tell me why the code I provided is not working? though the regex pattern identifies the dashes while I used <https://regexr.com/>

Comment: @PouyanKhodabakhsh `sed` does not support lookarounds. `-(?=[\w])` matches a `-` followed with a letter/digit/`_` in a PCRE pattern. Not all `sed`s support `\w`. GNU sed does. Anyway, since you need to replace the first `-` with `_` and the second one with `.` (i.e. different chars), you can't do this within a single `sed` command, you need either to use groups like in my single command, or use several commands (either `;`-separated or separated with `-e`, it depends on what sed version you have) like in Cyrus's solution.

Comment: Note that you may make matching even more precise if you make sure that Group 2 starts with a digit. Then it will look like `FILENAME=$(sed 's/\(.*\)-\([0-9][0-9.]*\)-/\1_\2./' <<< "$FILENAME")`

Answer (score 2):

I suggest:

```
echo 'x.xx.xxx.xxxx.api-6.8.25-SNAPSHOT.jar' | sed 's/-/_/; s/-/./'
```

Output:

```
x.xx.xxx.xxxx.api_6.8.25.SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Answer (score 2):

Pure bash solution without calling any external utility:

```sh
fn='xx.xxx.xxxx.api-6.8.25-SNAPSHOT.jar`
fn="${fn/-/_}"  # replace first - by _
fn="${fn/-/.}"  # replace next - by .
echo "$fn"

xx.xxx.xxxx.api_6.8.25.SNAPSHOT.jar
```